# .Include() Causes a gigantic union query and not all my children are populating?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

What could be the issue?  results.SubAreas **IS ALWAYS** null.
I have spent all afternoon reviewing all of my db constraints, code, pocos, mappings, dataannotations.  The results.ToString() query shows that it is joining to subareas, when I run the query in Management Studio it returns rows.  But it looks very strange.  After the query, I've included the poco definitions.

**Query**

```
var results = (from b in _context.Buildings
               .Include("SubAreas")
               .Include("ExtraFeatures")
               .Include("StructuralElements")
               where b.STRAP == strap && b.NUM == bld_num
               select b).FirstOrDefault();
```

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT 
[UnionAll2].[C2] AS [C1], 
[UnionAll2].[C3] AS [C2], 
[UnionAll2].[C4] AS [C3], 
[UnionAll2].[C5] AS [C4], 
[UnionAll2].[C6] AS [C5], 
[UnionAll2].[C7] AS [C6], 
[UnionAll2].[C8] AS [C7], 
[UnionAll2].[C9] AS [C8], 
[UnionAll2].[C10] AS [C9], 
[UnionAll2].[C1] AS [C10], 
[UnionAll2].[C11] AS [C11], 
[UnionAll2].[C12] AS [C12], 
[UnionAll2].[C13] AS [C13], 
[UnionAll2].[C14] AS [C14], 
[UnionAll2].[C15] AS [C15], 
[UnionAll2].[C16] AS [C16], 
[UnionAll2].[C17] AS [C17], 
[UnionAll2].[C18] AS [C18], 
[UnionAll2].[C19] AS [C19], 
[UnionAll2].[C20] AS [C20], 
[UnionAll2].[C21] AS [C21], 
[UnionAll2].[C22] AS [C22], 
[UnionAll2].[C23] AS [C23], 
[UnionAll2].[C24] AS [C24], 
[UnionAll2].[C25] AS [C25], 
[UnionAll2].[C26] AS [C26], 
[UnionAll2].[C27] AS [C27], 
[UnionAll2].[C28] AS [C28], 
[UnionAll2].[C29] AS [C29], 
[UnionAll2].[C30] AS [C30], 
[UnionAll2].[C31] AS [C31], 
[UnionAll2].[C32] AS [C32], 
[UnionAll2].[C33] AS [C33], 
[UnionAll2].[C34] AS [C34], 
[UnionAll2].[C35] AS [C35]
FROM  (SELECT 
    [UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [UnionAll1].[NUM] AS [C2], 
    [UnionAll1].[STRAP] AS [C3], 
    [UnionAll1].[NUM1] AS [C4], 
    [UnionAll1].[SITUS] AS [C5], 
    [UnionAll1].[TYPE] AS [C6], 
    [UnionAll1].[STYLE] AS [C7], 
    [UnionAll1].[YEAR_BUILT] AS [C8], 
    [UnionAll1].[GROSS_AREA] AS [C9], 
    [UnionAll1].[LIVING_AREA] AS [C10], 
    [UnionAll1].[STRAP1] AS [C11], 
    [UnionAll1].[BUILDING_NUM] AS [C12], 
    [UnionAll1].[SAR_LN_NUM] AS [C13], 
    [UnionAll1].[DSCR] AS [C14], 
    [UnionAll1].[GROSS_AREA1] AS [C15], 
    [UnionAll1].[VALUE] AS [C16], 
    [UnionAll1].[STRAP2] AS [C17], 
    [UnionAll1].[BUILDING_NUM1] AS [C18], 
    [UnionAll1].[C2] AS [C19], 
    [UnionAll1].[C3] AS [C20], 
    [UnionAll1].[C4] AS [C21], 
    [UnionAll1].[C5] AS [C22], 
    [UnionAll1].[C6] AS [C23], 
    [UnionAll1].[C7] AS [C24], 
    [UnionAll1].[C8] AS [C25], 
    [UnionAll1].[C9] AS [C26], 
    [UnionAll1].[C10] AS [C27], 
    [UnionAll1].[C11] AS [C28], 
    [UnionAll1].[C12] AS [C29], 
    [UnionAll1].[C13] AS [C30], 
    [UnionAll1].[C14] AS [C31], 
    [UnionAll1].[C15] AS [C32], 
    [UnionAll1].[C16] AS [C33], 
    [UnionAll1].[C17] AS [C34], 
    [UnionAll1].[C18] AS [C35]
    FROM  (SELECT 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[BUILDING_NUM] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
        [Extent1].[NUM] AS [NUM], 
        [Extent1].[STRAP] AS [STRAP], 
        [Extent1].[NUM] AS [NUM1], 
        [Extent1].[SITUS] AS [SITUS], 
        [Extent1].[TYPE] AS [TYPE], 
        [Extent1].[STYLE] AS [STYLE], 
        [Extent1].[YEAR_BUILT] AS [YEAR_BUILT], 
        [Extent1].[GROSS_AREA] AS [GROSS_AREA], 
        [Extent1].[LIVING_AREA] AS [LIVING_AREA], 
        [Extent2].[STRAP] AS [STRAP1], 
        [Extent2].[BUILDING_NUM] AS [BUILDING_NUM], 
        [Extent2].[SAR_LN_NUM] AS [SAR_LN_NUM], 
        [Extent2].[DSCR] AS [DSCR], 
        [Extent2].[GROSS_AREA] AS [GROSS_AREA1], 
        [Extent2].[VALUE] AS [VALUE], 
        [Extent2].[STRAP] AS [STRAP2], 
        [Extent2].[BUILDING_NUM] AS [BUILDING_NUM1], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C2], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C5], 
        CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS [C6], 
        CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS [C7], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C8], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C9], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C10], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C11], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C12], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C13], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C14], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C15], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C16], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C17], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C18]
        FROM  [dbo].[Buildings] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[SUB_AREAS] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[STRAP] = [Extent2].[STRAP]) AND ([Extent1].[NUM] = [Extent2].[BUILDING_NUM])
        WHERE ([Extent1].[STRAP] = '0001020003') AND ([Extent1].[NUM] = 1)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        2 AS [C1], 
        [Extent3].[NUM] AS [NUM], 
        [Extent3].[STRAP] AS [STRAP], 
        [Extent3].[NUM] AS [NUM1], 
        [Extent3].[SITUS] AS [SITUS], 
        [Extent3].[TYPE] AS [TYPE], 
        [Extent3].[STYLE] AS [STYLE], 
        [Extent3].[YEAR_BUILT] AS [YEAR_BUILT], 
        [Extent3].[GROSS_AREA] AS [GROSS_AREA], 
        [Extent3].[LIVING_AREA] AS [LIVING_AREA], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C2], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C5], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C6], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C7], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C8], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C9], 
        [Extent4].[STRAP] AS [STRAP1], 
        [Extent4].[LN_NUM] AS [LN_NUM], 
        [Extent4].[BUILDING_NUM] AS [BUILDING_NUM], 
        [Extent4].[DSCR] AS [DSCR], 
        [Extent4].[UNITS] AS [UNITS], 
        [Extent4].[UNIT_PRICE] AS [UNIT_PRICE], 
        [Extent4].[YEAR_BUILT] AS [YEAR_BUILT1], 
        [Extent4].[CD] AS [CD], 
        [Extent4].[STRAP] AS [STRAP2], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C10], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C11], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C12], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C13], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C14], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C15], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C16], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C17]
        FROM  [dbo].[Buildings] AS [Extent3]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[EXTRA_FEATURES] AS [Extent4] ON ([Extent3].[STRAP] = [Extent4].[STRAP]) AND ([Extent3].[NUM] = [Extent4].[BUILDING_NUM])
        WHERE ([Extent3].[STRAP] = '0001020003') AND ([Extent3].[NUM] = 1)) AS [UnionAll1]
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    3 AS [C1], 
    [Extent5].[NUM] AS [NUM], 
    [Extent5].[STRAP] AS [STRAP], 
    [Extent5].[NUM] AS [NUM1], 
    [Extent5].[SITUS] AS [SITUS], 
    [Extent5].[TYPE] AS [TYPE], 
    [Extent5].[STYLE] AS [STYLE], 
    [Extent5].[YEAR_BUILT] AS [YEAR_BUILT], 
    [Extent5].[GROSS_AREA] AS [GROSS_AREA], 
    [Extent5].[LIVING_AREA] AS [LIVING_AREA], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C2], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C5], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C6], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C7], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C8], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C9], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C10], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C11], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C12], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C13], 
    CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS [C14], 
    CAST(NULL AS decimal(18,2)) AS [C15], 
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C16], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C17], 
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C18], 
    [Extent6].[STRAP] AS [STRAP1], 
    [Extent6].[BUILDING_NUM] AS [BUILDING_NUM], 
    [Extent6].[LN_NUM] AS [LN_NUM], 
    [Extent6].[CATEGORY] AS [CATEGORY], 
    [Extent6].[DSCR] AS [DSCR], 
    [Extent6].[VALUE] AS [VALUE], 
    [Extent6].[STRAP] AS [STRAP2], 
    [Extent6].[BUILDING_NUM] AS [BUILDING_NUM1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Buildings] AS [Extent5]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[STRUCTURAL_ELEMENTS] AS [Extent6] ON ([Extent5].[STRAP] = [Extent6].[STRAP]) AND ([Extent5].[NUM] = [Extent6].[BUILDING_NUM])
    WHERE ([Extent5].[STRAP] = '0001020003') AND ([Extent5].[NUM] = 1)) AS [UnionAll2]
ORDER BY [UnionAll2].[C3] ASC, [UnionAll2].[C4] ASC, [UnionAll2].[C1] ASC
```

**Model classes**

```
[Table("STRUCTURAL_ELEMENTS")]
public class StructuralElement
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string STRAP { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int BUILDING_NUM { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int LN_NUM { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public string CATEGORY { get; set; }
    public string DSCR { get; set; }
    public string VALUE { get; set; }

}

[Table("SUB_AREAS")]
public class SubArea
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string STRAP { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int BUILDING_NUM { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int SAR_LN_NUM { get; set; }

    public string DSCR { get; set; }
    public int GROSS_AREA { get; set; }
    public int VALUE { get; set; }
}

[Table("EXTRA_FEATURES")]
public class ExtraFeature
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string STRAP { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int BUILDING_NUM { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int LN_NUM { get; set; }

    public string DSCR { get; set; }
    public decimal? UNITS { get; set; }
    public decimal? UNIT_PRICE { get; set; }
    public int? YEAR_BUILT { get; set; }
    public string CD { get; set; }

}

public class Building
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string STRAP { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int NUM { get; set; }
    public string SITUS { get; set; }
    public string TYPE { get; set; }
    public string STYLE { get; set; }
    //public string CLASS { get; set; }
    public int? YEAR_BUILT { get; set; }
    public int? GROSS_AREA { get; set; }
    public int? LIVING_AREA { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("STRAP,BUILDING_NUM")]
    public  ICollection<StructuralElement> StructuralElements { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("STRAP,BUILDING_NUM")]
    public  ICollection<ExtraFeature> ExtraFeatures { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("STRAP,BUILDING_NUM")]
    public  ICollection<SubArea> SubAreas { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: You need to show us the Building entity code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My keys in the null tables were stored with whitespace, so EF wasn't linking them to their parents.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like kind of optimization. You are trying to load Building with related collections. Now imagine that building has 100 SubAreas, 100 ExtraFeatures and 100 StructuralElements, what naive JOIN would produce? Correct, one million rows. ORMs are not so stupid as they are often considered to be, query with UNION will return 301 row.